# No sound after connecting to WebRTC when app is launched in background using PushKit and CallKit on the lock screen

Tags: swift, webrtc, callkit, pushkit, ios-background-mode

Everything works fine if we launch the app in the foreground. But there is an issue when the app is previously killed and is restarted by receiving a PushKit notification on the lock screen.

When the app receives a PushKit notification we display the CallKit UI. This works correctly. The user is able to answer the call and establish a connection via WebRTC. But there is no audio at all.

The strange thing is that if the user opens the app from CallKit screen by tapping on the application icon, the audio starts and works as expected. So it looks like the problem is with the audio session configuration. Maybe for some reason, iOS doesn't allow our audio session to be activated.

We're using Google's WebRTC library:

```
pod 'GoogleWebRTC',             '1.1.26115'
```

We tried different approaches:

1. Enabling/disabling audio background mode.
2. Configuring audio session before and after the `didActivate` callback is received from CallKit delegate.
3. Configuring audio session manually and using `RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance` from WebRTC library.
4. Enabling and disabling `RTCAudioSession.useManualAudio`.

This is the scenario where we encounter the issue:

1. Kill the app. Lock the phone.
2. Call this user from another phone.
3. PushKit launches the app, the app presents CallKit screen, the user answers the call.
4. The connection establishes correctly. The call is active but there is no sound on both ends.
5. Tap on the app icon (most bottom right) on the CallKit screen and unlock the phone. The audio starts.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to configure the audio session before calling `reportNewIncomingCall(with:update:completion:)`?

Comment: Probably this same issue as below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070163/callkitno-sound-when-i-use-webrtc/55781328?fbclid=IwAR1-FiiHzaB7Wx-PHO7cC-CfTbl83Wmd_vLAP-rptRKqynLINeMheBN6DCs#55781328
Please check my answer

Comment: Did you solve it? Have exectly the same problem and tried a all this ways, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a specific issue with the audio I/O and `CallKit`. When you are about to receive an incoming call, you must configure audio session for VoIP calls then, but do not activate it, just set category, mode and buffer.

Example for configuring Audio Session for `CallKit` incoming call:

```
func configureAudioSession() {
    let sharedSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try sharedSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try sharedSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat)
        try sharedSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(TimeInterval(0.005))
        try sharedSession.setPreferredSampleRate(44100.0)
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Failed to configure `AVAudioSession`")
    }
}
```

Then, when you answer the incoming Call, `CallKit` will activate the audio session for you, and you will receive a callback from CXProvider:

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
    // Start call audio I/O here
}
```

In that delegate callback, you should start your call audio, not before. If WebRTC call audio I/O was started before, ***the CallKit will terminate it and there will be no sound.***

Comment: How can I give the audioSession focus to webrtc when screen is locked? By default the output audio starts only when I unlock the screen.

Comment: I belive that `func provider(_ provider: didActivate:)` audio session delegate method is called when you answer the incoming audio/video call. In that callback, you need to enable audio processor, up until then audio processor should be disabled, otherwise the CallKit will terminate all running audio IOs, resulting in no sound during a call

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with linphone-sdk and CallKit.
And the problem in my case was a missing audio key in Info.plist.
You need to have these keys, if you want you app works with AVAudioSession in background mode.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
        <string>voip</string>
        <string>audio</string>
</array>
```